# Magento topSearch doesn't work in template

Tags: magento

I want to take topSearch from the header and copy it to a content page, so I cut from `header.phtml` and added to `3columns.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch'); ?>
```

It doesn't work, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/view/viewthread/181044/#t232482

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for change the search bar position header to top links.
go to:-

> app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml

replace this code

```
reference name="header"
```

with this

```
reference name="top.menu"
```

Changes css  according to your design.

it woks for me

Answer (score 1):

**.form-search**

*margin-left: 899px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: absolute;*
add the above css 
let the search box on the header itself 
just using the absolute property you can play to display its position
contact me on my email for furthur help.
Thanks.

**Suraj Mishra
Magento Extension Developer
msooraz@gmail.com**

Comment: You can provide further help/solution/clarification needed over here only. So that other users having same kind of problem can also get help from that. Please visit [What kind of behavior is expected of users? - Avoid overt self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)